# Reorganize code: from many function to interface system

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I currently have a class with some code which basically calls some functions and then perform the max/min on all the results

```
    float limitOtherSide = limitImposedByPreviousVerticesOnOtherSide(other, pNewX, minimumDistance, pIsUpper);
    float limitInterpolation = limitToPreventInterpolatedPointsTooClose(other, pNewX, temp, minimumDistance, pIsUpper);
    float limitToPreventChocksOnMiddleSCurve = limitToAvoidChockesAlongAllTheSCurve(other, pNewX, temp, minimumDistance, playerWidth, pIsUpper);
    float limitToGrantMinimumDistanceVertically = limitToAvoidChockesAlongAllTheSCurve(other, pNewX, temp, minimumDistance, 0, pIsUpper);
    float limitOutOfScreenInterpolation = limitToPreventeForcedOutOfScreenNextOppositeVertex(other, pNewX, minimumDistance, pIsUpper);
    float limitChocke =  limitToAvoidChocke(other, pNewX, minimumDistance, pIsUpper);

    if(pIsUpper) {
        float max1 = Math.max(limitOtherSide, limitInterpolation);
        float max2 = Math.max(limitToPreventChocksOnMiddleSCurve, limitOutOfScreenInterpolation);
        float minimumY = Math.max(Math.max(max1, limitToGrantMinimumDistanceVertically), Math.max(max2, limitChocke));
        newLowerY = MathUtilities.clamp(minimumY, 0.1f, 1);
        newUpperY = 1.f;
    } else {
        float min1 = Math.min(limitOtherSide, limitInterpolation);
        float min2 = Math.min(limitToPreventChocksOnMiddleSCurve, limitOutOfScreenInterpolation);
        float maximumY = Math.min(Math.min(min1, limitToGrantMinimumDistanceVertically), Math.min(min2, limitChocke));
        newUpperY = MathUtilities.clamp(maximumY, 0 , 0.9f);
        newLowerY = 0.f;
    }
    float newY = (float) RANDOM.nextGaussian(newLowerY, newUpperY);
```

I'd like to reorganize it for several reasons:

- the functions are almost pure and self contained
- I'd like to be able to switch on and off easily which checks to perform (even if it's a matter of changing the source code)
- I'd like to separate the limit checking from the rest of the code of the class which is more general about how to generate points
- I plan on adding more functions, which will clutter the class even more
- Being able to change only one part of the code to add a new check instead of having to concatenate even more Math.max and add variables and so on in the calling function

So, I was thinking about changing the code to something like

```
List<Filter> mFilters; //initialized in the constructor
[...]
if(pIsUpper) {
    for(Filter f : mFilters) {
        newLowerY = Math.max(newLowerY, f.doFilter(args..));
    }
    newLowerY = MathUtilities.clamp(newLowerY , 0.1f, 1);
    newUpperY = 1.f;
} else {
    for(Filter f : mFilters) {
        newUpperY = Math.min(newUpperY , f.doFilter(args..));
    }
    newUpperY = MathUtilities.clamp(newUpperY , 0.1f, 1);
    newLowerY = 0.f;
}
```

The point is: I don't know how to define the interface. As you might have noticed all the functions have some common basic arguments, but then they differ for a few of them.

My options:

1. Make the interface take all the possible arguments, and then ignore them in the implementation. This is not doable as in my current code I call the same function with 2 different arguments, and thus I'd need to make 2 separate implementations of that functions that use 2 separate arguments and put both of them in the interface (really ugly solution)
2. Implement the interface with 2 methods, one is a doFilter(), the other is a generic passArgument(Object ...), but this is not different than calling all the functions like now, but the result in a list, and then compute the max/min of it. Moreover I'd like to keep code "clean" and passing unchecked objects looks like a really ugly solution
3. Implement the interface as doFilter with all the common args, and for the remaining specific arguments pass a callback to the constructor of the filter, which can be used to get the additional parameters. I originally went for this solution, but then noticed one of the functions need a parameter that is calculated inside the calling function, so I either make that parameter a field in the class and return the field in the callback or I pass a new callback which passes the new value every time. I don't really like this last change I'd need to do.

So, I'm asking you, is there a paradigm/best practice/design pattern to solve this kind of problem?

Am I worrying over a non-problem? Right now the class is not huge, but at least half of it (if not more) is composed by these functions.

Answer (score 1):

One more approach is to create an "agument object" - this will be a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) that is meant to hold all the required information to all methods, and pass only it.

Each implementing method will recieve this object, and query the needed field in order to produce the relevant result.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fix the problem caused by limitToPreventChocksOnMiddleSCurve and limitToGrantMinimumDistanceVertically, which call the same function with 2 different arguments. In the solution you proposed (which actually is little different from solution 2) I'd need to write that method 2 times once querying one field and once querying the other filed. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Makers_F You can create an abstract class that implement the common functionality and each implementing concrete class uses it.

Answer (score 0):

The Interface should have one function of no arguments.

```
interface Filter
{
    float doFilter();
}
```

The different implementations take their values at construction. Then you don't have to worry about passing arguments.

Comment: This works only for some functions, as some of them take different arguments every time they are called. That would mean instantiating a new class at every cycle. At that point, it's just better to call a function instead